# Renaming files will not work with >1 GB file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the below code to rename few hundreds of files, it works great when the file is smaller than 1GB in size, but when it encounter larger files it doesn't extract anything and the resulted file name is blank.

```
import os, linecache

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.startswith("out"): continue # less deep
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename) # folderpath + filename
    fourteenline = linecache.getline(file_path, 14) # maybe 13 for 0-based index?
    new_file_name = fourteenline[40:40+50].rstrip() # staring at 40 with length of 50
    os.rename(file_path, os.path.join(path, new_file_name))
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee that your file has at least 14 lines? The documentation says that getline never raises an exception, even when the line is not found. Also, an example for your fourteenline variable would be nice.

Comment: Yes, each file has a header of 25 lines even if it has no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename) 
    fb=open(file_path)
    secondline=next(islice(fb,1,2))
    fb.close()
    print(secondline)
    new_file_name = secondline[28:28 + 70].rstrip() 
    Filenamenew = new_file_name
    os.rename(file_path, os.path.join(path, Filenamenew))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `linecache`. It reads the entire files in memory and fails quietly when running out of memory.

Just `open` each file and read 14 lines in a simple loop, or with help of `itertools.islice`.